# Matlab Quadratic equation

Tags: matlab, quadratic

Struggling with a MATLAB quadratic equation. I keep getting a complex number as my answer and other errors keep occurring.

> Write a MATLAB function that solves a quadratic equation of the form
>   `a*x^2 + b*x + c = 0`
>
> The syntax of your function should take the form
>
> ```
> [quadRoots1,quadRoots2] = Q1_quadratic (a,b,c);
> ```
>
> where `a`, `b` and `c` are the quadratic coefficients; and `quadRoots1` and `quadRoots2` are the two determined roots. For the case where only one root is present (for example when `a=1`, `b=2` and `c=1`), you should set your second output to `NaN` (not a number). If no roots are present, then set both outputs to `NaN`.

Comment: It's been a while, but if memory serves, if b^2 - 4ac < 0, then your roots are complex. If you are only solving for real roots, you are going to need to take care of that.

Comment: Your question states what to do when there are no real roots: maybe you could write an `if` statement for checking if this is the case

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework and the OP has shown no attempt.

Comment: *I keep getting a complex number as my answer and other errors keep occurring.* What have you tried? Edit your question and add your best attempt so far. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check if the number under the root sign in your [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) is:

- Positive (`>0`): two distinct real roots,
- Equal to zero (`==0`): single real numbered degenerate root (or, rather, two non-distinct roots).
- Negative (`<0`: your roots are complex (recall `sqrt(-1) = i`, with [our imaginary unit `i`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit)). From the sound of your question specs, it seems you are to treat complex as if *"no roots are present"*.

You can check the cases above in your function `Q1_quadratic(...)` using an `if-elseif-else` clause, e.g.:

```
function [quadRoots1, quadRoots2] = Q1_quadratic(a, b, c)

  d = b^2 - 4*a*c; % your number under the root sign in quad. formula

  % real numbered distinct roots?
  if d > 0
    quadRoots1 = (-b+sqrt(d))/(2*a);
    quadRoots2 = (-b-sqrt(d))/(2*a);
  % real numbered degenerate root?
  elseif d == 0 
    quadRoots1 = -b/(2*a);
    quadRoots2 = NaN;
  % complex roots, return NaN, NaN
  else
    quadRoots1 = NaN;
    quadRoots2 = NaN;
  end    
end
```

Test:

```
% distinct real roots: expects [2, -8]
[a, b] = Q1_quadratic(1, 6, -16)
    % OK!

% degenerate real root: expects [-1, NaN]
[a, b] = Q1_quadratic(1, 2, 1)
    % OK!

% complex roots: expects [NaN, NaN]
[a, b] = Q1_quadratic(2, 2, 1)
    % OK!
```

Comment: This is obviously homework, and the OP has shown no attempt. Why would you give a complete answer?

Comment: @Jubobs Ow my bad, I skimmed over the question to quickly to realize it's obviously a homework question (very obvious now after the quote environment edit by Steve). I agree homework questions shouldn't be answered in such completeness, my apologies, I simply missed this one out of my own obliviousness.

Comment: That's fine; I'm glad you didn't do it on purpose.

Comment: @Jubobs I'm glad you told me. With this sorted out, should I delete this answer now, do you think? I presume the question will be closed sooner or later anyway.

Comment: I'd say leave it. It's probably too late to take it down now, and it does have value.